# How to return multiple custom values in model Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, affiliate

What I'm trying to do is an affiliate program and I wish when I call an scope it returns all my desired values. There will be a logic for calculation of the values for the platform, seller and affiliate.

What I have already is:

```
public function scopeProfitPlatform($query) {
    return $query->sum('price')*0.6;
}

public function scopeProfitAffiliate($query) {
    return $query->sum('price')*0.05;
}

public function scopeProfitBuyer($query) {
    return $query->sum('price')*0.35;
}
```

This works, however I'd like to make this more simple. So instead of having to call `Order::profitplatform() and order::profitaffiliate, etc....` I wanted to call Order::profit() and it would return all those values to me all at once.

I tried to use Order::profitplatform()->profitaffiliate() but it doesn't work.

I was thinking of creating a specific service for this purpose however I don't think it's necessary. I think it's possible to with scopes or something else similar, however I'm not finding the solution.

I appreciate any suggestions, ideas and solutions for simplifying this problem. Thanks.

Comment: This is more of a code review question.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Order::profitplatform()->profitaffiliate()->get();

Comment: Error: "Call to a member function profit() on string"